Questions get answered by a user, how to store historical data alongside the answer?
I'm building a database where a User can answer Questions, each Question belongs to a Category.
Now what if someone changes a question or category name later, I need to store the historical data of the question/category alongside the answer.
But I also need to do calculations on these rows, for example, for CategoryID 10, what's the average score for all questions, so storing categoryName or questionName in the Answers table won't be enough.
Is there a pattern/method I can use for this? Thanks
This is the current database model
CREATE TABLE Categories (
    CategoryID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    CategoryName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Questions (
    QuestionID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    CategoryID INT,
    QuestionText TEXT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (CategoryID) REFERENCES Categories(CategoryID)
);

CREATE TABLE Users (
    UserID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    UserName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    -- other user details...
);

CREATE TABLE Answers (
    AnswerID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    UserID INT,
    QuestionID INT,
    AnswerText TEXT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (UserID) REFERENCES Users(UserID),
    FOREIGN KEY (QuestionID) REFERENCES Questions(QuestionID)
);



Now what if someone changes a question or category name later, I need to store the historical data of the question/category alongside the answer.

No, having this stored alongside the answer would lead to massive duplication of the data.
The normalized solution is to have a additional history table for each entity you want to keep track of e.g.:
CREATE TABLE CategoryHistory (
  CategoryID   INT          NOT NULL,
  UpdatedDtm   DATETIME     NOT NULL,
  CategoryName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT CategoryHistory_pk 
    PRIMARY KEY (CategoryId, UpdatedDtm)
  CONSTRAINT Category_Was_CategoryHistory_fk 
    FOREIGN KEY (CategoryId) REFERENCES Category (CategoryId)
);

You would need to additionally track when an answer was submitted, lets say in a DATETIME column AnswerDtm, in order to be able to get the category/question data as it was at that time:

Get the current data when AnswertDtm > MAX UpdatedDtm.
Else get the most recent row in history table where AnswerDtm < UpdatedDtm

Aside from that, Answers.AnswerId is totally useless. You can use a primary key like (UserId, QuestionId) or (UserId, QuestionId, AnswerDtm) depending on whether a user is allowed multiple answers or not.
